# Hibernate: @PreUpdate and @PrePersist not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to make Hibernate set an attribute `lastUpdated` whenever a change on the entity occurs. I use the annotations `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` and in my logic that should suffice:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class DomainEntity {
    @Id
    @Include
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastUpdated;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    private void onUpdate() {
        lastUpdated = new Date();
    }
}
```

I safe the entity using the repository:

```
domainRepository.save(domainEntity);
```

But the attribute `lastUpdated` is not updated. Do I miss something here?
When I save the entity as a new entity to the database, the field is set correctly. When I already have the entity in the database and I only update it, it is not set. Why?

```
Optional<DomainEntity> domainOptionalOld = domainRepository.findByName(domainEntity.getName());
domainOptionalOld.ifPresent(d -> domainEntity.setId(d.getId()));
domainRepository.save(domainEntity);
```

*Update:*
I have around 14 entity types which all have the same attribute `lastUpdated` and the above described `onUpdate()` method. With 12 it works and with two it doesn't. Is there any known issue with the annotations? Maybe that it doesn't work with other annotations like `@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` or `@Data`?

Comment: `@PreUpdate` is executed when you flush the session

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Flush is triggered by hibernate whenever it estimated necessary : before selecting data possibly modified by previous queries, before transaction commit... You can also force it by calling flush() on the entityManager.

Comment: I suggest that if you don't know about sessions, flushing, etc. that you should learn more about JPA and Hibernate before continuing to use those technologies. ORM is not a trivial topic and many mistakes can be made by developers using it who don't really udnerstand it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your concern E-Riz. I'm not sure how that helps with my problem at hand, but I will definitely consider it.

Comment: I don't think flushing is the problem. I process around 14 entity types and the domain is the first. The other types are all saved - that means hibernate flushes them to the db, therefore the domain should also be flushed. Right?

Comment: Did you actually change the contents of the entity? If Hibernate determines the entity is not dirty, then obviously it won't execute an update and also not call any listeners.

Comment: I think that might be it. So is there a way to make hibernate call the onUpdate() everytime I perform save()? Maybe a different annotation?